# How can I use Adwaita Dark for all applications in Gnome 3?

Tags: gnome3, gtk, theme, gtk3

I noticed that some applications use the Adwaita Dark theme, while others use the light one. Is there a way to make all applications use the Dark one?

Comment: Adding screenshots or at least mentioning what applications are having this issue, would be helpful.

Comment: According to `gnome-session --version`, I have Gnome `3.4.2.1`, but as I use OpenBox as WM (are you using Metacity?), instead of the solution below, I use `obconf` to change theme (and set other preferences).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Replacing the main theme with the dark one in `/usr/share/themes` is not an ideal solution as each time `gnome-themes` is updated your theme will revert to default. It's preferable to properly configure your user account to use the dark theme, that way your settings will be preserved between updates. You can do that:

- Manually: create (open if already present) the following file:

  `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini`

  edit like this:

  `[Settings]`
  `gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme=1`

---

- Via `gnome-tweak-tool` (which essentially does the same thing as above, writing the same file):

  [image: GNOME3 dark theme mode switch in gnome-tweak-tool]

---

### GTK2 Problem

This answer is indeed the *ideal* and *"safe"* (i.e no need to replace/mod any system files) method. However, currently neither this method nor [Jeff's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63389/how-can-i-use-adwaita-dark-for-all-applications-gnome-3-4/63390#63390) works for all apps. Coz only *GNOME3/GTK3* has support for the `dark theme mode`. As of now, there are still many apps (for example those written in GNOME2/GTK2, Qt, wxWidgets, Java, etc) which don't use GTK3 and remain on the old GTK2 theming. To make those apps dark, replacing/modding the GTK2 part(`$ACTIVE_THEME/gtk-2.0/gtkrc`) of the currently active theme works. To know more, see [the answer to "Firefox not affected by gtk theme"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/337018/firefox-not-affected-by-gtk-theme/337021#337021).

As GTK2 is deprecated and superseded by GTK3, all actively developed GTK2 apps are getting ported to or replaced by GTK3. Sooner or later, other toolkits like Qt, wxWidgets, etc may also implement support for GTK3. By that time, this method may become valid for all(maybe almost all) apps.

Comment: I haven't tested this, so I'm giving you the benefit of the doubt :) This does seem neater.

Comment: My version of gnome-tweak-tool (updated AFAIK) doesn't have this option. Manually adding that file works fine after reboot.

Comment: This does not work for all applications, e.g. Firefox. I'm going to try this now: http://askubuntu.com/questions/337018/firefox-not-affected-by-gtk-theme

Comment: I found using [this](http://cbowman57.deviantart.com/art/Adwaita-Dark-3-14-rev-2-492714039) theme worked quite well - I replaced the original Adwaita theme in `/usr/share/themes` with it and it works quite well :)

Comment: For GTK+ 2, install the package `gnome-themes-standard`, then select its `Adwaita-dark` as your system theme. Having a separate name means this can point GTK+ 2 at a port of Adwaita:dark from GTK+ 3 to GTK+ 2.

Answer (score 6):

Simply replace the main theme with the dark one (in a special copy of Adwaita in your home dir):

```
mkdir -p ~/.themes
cp -r /usr/share/themes/Adwaita ~/.themes/Darkwaita
cd ~/.themes/Darkwaita/gtk-3.0
cp gtk-dark.css gtk.css
```

Then use a tool like gnome-tweak-tool to set Darkwaita as your gtk theme, and the changes should take effect immediately.

Comment: Although it work, after an update it could be revert to the default.

Comment: That issue can be avoided by copying the theme into your home directory first: `cp -r /usr/share/themes/Adwaita ~/.themes/Darkwaita; cp ~/.themes/Adwaita/gtk-3.0/gtk{-dark,}.css` and then using `gnome-tweak-tool` to select Darkwaita theme.

Comment: This no longer works in Ubuntu Vivid, the there is no longer a gtk-dark.css file and the full content of gtk.css is just `/* Adwaita is the default theme of GTK+ 3, this file is not used */` so... fuck.